# Pandas mistake while sorting values

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to sort my dataframe based on 'date' and 'hour' columns. Its sorting 01/11/2020 before dates like 24/10/2020.

```
df = pd.read_csv("some_folder")   
df = df.sort_values(by = ['date','hour']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image: Code Output]

In the picture you can see the sorting error.

Comment: It's doing a string comparison. If you change the formatting of your dates to be something more like `yyyy-mm-dd`, then string sorting and date sorting will line up.

Answer (score 4):

Try to convert the column `date` to datetime before sorting ([pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime)):

```
df = pd.read_csv("some_folder")   
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)     # <-- convert the column to `datetime`
df = df.sort_values(by = ['date','hour']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @LiadHa Can you edit your question and put there sample of CSV (in text form - so we can copy it)?

Comment: sorry but thats confidential

Comment: @LiadHa - remove the confidential part, but show the date string with random values.

Comment: 24/10/2020
24/10/2020
24/10/2020
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
25/10/2020
this is how to dates are represanted in the csv file

Comment: Please include input data and the expected output in your question to provide a [reproducilbe example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This solution does work correctly for your input data.

Comment: i cant include the input data.
I excpet to get a sorted by date,hour dataframe, for now the sort puts 01-11-2020 before 25-10-2020.